# Creating empty eclipse project using sbt

Tags: scala, sbteclipse

When I run `eclipse` in sbt with *build.sbt* having,

```
name := "test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
```

It had `build.sbt,  project and  target` but, in tutorial I was following it was mentioned `src/main/scala, src/main/java, ..test` will be available where I can code in eclipse by importing.

What am I doing wrong?

I have added `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")` in `~\.sbt\0.13`

Appreciate some help

Comment: Just tried your exact build.sbt and I get all those folders. Don't know if it makes any difference, but my plugin is version 2.5.0 and it's located in ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt.

Comment: okay let me uninstall and add old plugin and try thanks for response

Comment: Actually worked when I changed plugin to "2.5.0" Thanks again